# PgBouncer throwing PSQLException: ERROR: unsupported pkt type: 80 when issuing query "SHOW POOLS" on "pgbouncer" database via JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pgbouncer

When trying to issue "SHOW POOLS" or any stats query command on pgbouncer database via JDBC, facing the below exception.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unsupported pkt type: 80
    at
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
    at
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
    at
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
    at
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:406)
    at
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:286)
```

JDBC code:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://"+ipaddress+":"+port+"/"+database; 
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userName, password);
statement = con.createStatement(); statement.executeQuery("SHOW POOLS");



JDBC Driver Version: 42.2.14 ;
PgBouncer Version: 1.14.0 ;
Postgres Version: 11.4;
```

PS:
Manually able to connect to pgbouncer database and issue all pgbouncer admin commands like **SHOW POOLS** or **SHOW STATS**. Just not able to execute the same from JDBC.

Comment: Did the answer provided work for you? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC use extended query protocol by default, try simple protocol for such query

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://"+ipaddress+":"+port+"/"+database+"?preferQueryMode=simple";
```

PGBouncer currently supports *only* the simple protocol - the packet type 80 is for 'Parse', which is the first step in the extended protocol. The message you see in the exception PSQLException actually comes from PGBouncer.